# Find the values of $\sinh 2x$ and $\cosh 2x$, if $\sinh 3x = 3/4$

Tags: trigonometry

First, use $\sinh 3x = 3/4$ to find the value of $\sinh x$.

Then, we know that

$$\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$$

By substituting the value for $\sinh x$ in this equation we can find the value for $\cosh x$.

Then use the $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$ to find $\sinh 2x$ and $\cosh 2x$ by substituting in

- $ \sinh 2x = 2 \sinh x \cosh x$
- $ \cosh 2x = 2 \cosh^2x - 1 $

Right now I can't seem to find a way to obtain the $\sinh x$ value from the given $\sinh 3x$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Write out the equation in terms of exponentials and take $A=e^{3x}$. You will get a quadratic in $A$ from where you should be able to solve for $x$.

Comment: Please use brackets with trig functions, so that it is clear what you mean. For instance, what is $2 \cosh^2x -1$ supposed to be?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent it isn’t totally clear where the brackets are supposed to be, so I cannot edit the OPs post to clean it up (lest my edits be incorrect).

Comment: @A-LevelStudent yes, but, sometimes, new posters (like the OP) have inconsistent and unclear LaTeX formatting, so, without brackets, it isn’t clear whether something was meant to be an exponent for one part of the question and  not the other part, or if it’s just bad LaTeX formatting. So, for instance, $\cosh 2x$ vs $\cosh^2x$. A lot of newcomers have quite poor LaTeX formatting, so this is a concern when trying to edit and clean up their posts.

Comment: @ThePointer I see what you mean, thanks for clarifying. In this case I think it's clear that the OP means what is written as the identity stated ($\cosh 2x\equiv2\cosh^2(x)-1$)  is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse function of $f(x)=\sinh x$ is defined as $\operatorname{arsinh}x$, and it is quite simple to show that $$\operatorname{arsinh} x=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
To solve your equation then, since we have
$$\sinh 3x=\frac{3}{4}$$
that means that
$$3x=\operatorname{arsinh}\frac{3}{4}=\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}+1}\right)=\ln2$$
You should be able to do the rest yourself. If you do need more help please don't hesitate to ask :)

---

By definition, $$\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
so setting $x=\frac{1}{3}\ln2$, we can see that
$$\sinh x=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{3}\ln2}-e^{-\frac{1}{3}\ln2}}{2}=\frac{2^{1/3}-0.5^{1/3}}{2}$$

---

### An attempt that fails:

You may be tempted to use the formula for $\sinh3x$, derived below, but that isn't very helpful I'm afraid.

We know that
$$\sinh(2x)\equiv 2\sinh x\cosh x\quad\cosh(2x)\equiv 1+2\sinh^2x$$
and more generally,
$$\sinh(A+B)\equiv\sinh A\cosh B+\sinh B\cosh A.$$
Here's the sneaky part. We can write $\sinh(3x)$ as $\sinh(2x+x)$ and then use the addition formula above!
$$\begin{align}\sinh(3x)&\equiv\sinh(2x+x)\equiv\sinh2x\cosh x+\sinh x\cosh2x\\
&\equiv2\sinh x\cosh^2x+\sinh x(1+2\sinh^2x)\\
&\equiv2\sinh x(1+\sinh^2x)+\sinh x +2\sinh^3x\\
&\equiv3\sinh x+4\sinh^3x\end{align}$$
So your equation is really
$$3\sinh x+4\sinh^3x=\frac{3}{4}$$
The problem is, solving this equation for $\sinh x$ is very hard without using the cubic formula.

Comment: Used your answer to find the value of $x$, however I am only able to find a decimal answer for $sinhx$. Do you know a way to find the non-decimal value of $sinhx$?

Comment: To eventually find the value of $sinh 2x$ and $cosh 2x$ a non-decimal value will be required.

Comment: Or could you suggest another method to find $sinh 2x$ and $cosh2x$ rather than the one I pointed out in the original question.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I leave the answer in-terms of $sinh 2x$ and $cosh 2x$ ?

Comment: @unknown No; use the definition of $\sinh2x$ and $\cosh2x$, ie $\cosh2x=\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}$ and $\sinh2x=\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2}$ and plug in $x=\frac{1}{3}\ln2$, and there's your answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @unknown No problem! If my answer was very helpful then please consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark